# Slow performSegue in tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath - iOS12

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, ios12

Has anyone experienced this? I'm, not 100% certain that this is iOS12-related but calling performSegue inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath has a delay of like 1-2 secs.

I already tried different things that I found elsewhere like bringing it to the main thread but nothing works. Not sure if this is a bug or not but I haven't seen anyone talking about it online.

Comment: Does this happen also on a device or just a simulator?

Comment: Also, why are you thinking it's an issue with iOS 12? Are you saying you haven't had this issue with iOS 11?

Comment: Ok, it's happening on (iPhone7Plus) for both iOS12(device) iOS11(simulator) .

Comment: its better if you can put didSelectRowAtIndexPath method code in your question that can helps us to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Try your code inside main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueName", sender: self)
}
```

This worked for me, As sometimes we can not get e main thread which is important if you are working with some UI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the prepare Method? if so, what are you doing before the Segue?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ExampleSegue" {
        let ChangeVC = segue.destination as! ExampleViewController
        ...
    }   
}
```

Have you tried to hand over the index path of your selected Row to a different ViewController? And decide there what to do?

Comment: Not at all. It's a straight up performSegue. Not passing any information to the other VC. That's why I found it really odd.